# Is it possible to create conditional rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting

Here is my predicament.

I've inherited support on a website and tasked with moving it to a new host.

An issue I have encountered with this is that there is an uploads folder with over 93,000 files in it. I have to move these files into a 'Year\Month' directory structure, based on the date of the files, while keeping external links alive.

Putting aside the complexity of modifying the database information, the rows relating to the individual files, to reflect the new structure is it possible to create conditional rewrite statements.

What I mean is if a request is made to find a file in that directory, specifically in the root 'Uploads' folder, that there would be a list of corresponding ReWrite rules reflecting the new positions.

Would having this many rules have a serious performance issue?

I suppose I could simplify it further where instead of putting the existing files into 'Year/Month' structure I could put them into an alphanumeric structure based on the first character of the files i.e. files starting with symbols would all go in the 'Sorted\Symbols' folder, files starting with 1 will go in the 'Sorted\1' folder and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im going to assume you're using Apache

Yes it is possible to create conditional rewrite rules using `RewriteCond`

See here for more info: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond

If you are sensible with how you set it up, it shouldnt have a noticable impact on performance.
For example if the first rewrite condition you can provide can eliminate all the files that wont be rewritten then it shouldn';t create a big performance hit.

E.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mydir
```

Only perform rewrites on requests with uri starting with mydir

Comment: The issue with that is going forward new files will be separated into year and month directories. So simply checking for files that are under the root directory won't do. Can I tell it to only look for requested files that are in the ROOT of /uploads only?

Comment: Yeah you can it is just a case of getting the regex right. Something like `^/uploads/(^/)*/$` that probably wont work but something similar might.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. I just wanted to get some ideas on what would be best and I guess what I thought, as you mentioned, is the simplest route.